# Dynamic programming in Haskell

Tags: haskell, dynamic-programming

Does Haskell provide any tools for dynamic programming? In a procedural language, I would use an array to store the calculations based on a recurrence relation. How do I do something similar in Haskell?

Comment: first hit in google "haskell dynamic-programming" http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Dynamic_programming_example

Comment: Haskell is one of the best procedural languages there is! :) You can probably implement the same code in a suitable monad with few major changes.

Comment: @PeterHall I haven't learned about monads yet ;-(

Comment: @epsilonhalbe Thanks for the link. I really should follow my own advice and do more research before asking Qs here.

Answer (score 6):

Many different ways depending on the situation.  That said, often simple dynamic programming algorithms are far simpler in Haskell than in other languages because of Haskelll is lazy

Consider the Fibonacci function (the "Hello World" of functional programming)

```
fib n | n < 2 = 1
fib n | otherwise = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
```

this runs in exponential time (grr).  We could trivially store all the values of fib in a lazy infinitely long list

```
fibs = map fib [0..]
```

now we can observe that

```
fibs !! n
 = (map fib [0..]) !! n =
 = fib ([0..] !! n)
 = fib n
```

so far this doesn't help us, but we can use this equivalence to our advantage

```
fib n | n < 2 = 1
fib n | otherwise = (fibs !! (n-1)) + (fibs !! (n-2)) where
  fibs = map fib [0..]
```

this provides a linear time solution to the Fibonacci function (although it leaks space...don't actually do it this way), and only works because Haskell is lazy.  We defined an infinite data-structure in terms of a recurrence relation on itself.  The miracle is that this runs in finite time (non strictness), that it runs in linear time is a product of the time optimality of call-by-need (Haskell's cost model).  The reason for this linear time performance is that each entry in `fibs` is computed at most once (or possibly never).